# Syntax of an un-named function pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I was looking into most vexing parse, and I stumbled upon something like this:

```
Foo bar(Baz()); // bar is a function that takes a pointer to a function that returns a Baz and returns a Foo
```

This is quite different from the typical syntax of `return-type(*name)(parameters)`. Are the parenthesis present the parenthesis for the parameter list, or are they for the name?

Comment: Oh my C++, syntax can be confusing sometimes. If `Baz` were a _function_ of no parameters returning a `Foo`, then that declares `bar` as a variable of type `Foo` initialized to `Baz()`. But if `Baz` is a _type_ then `bar` is declared to be a function?! Crazy....

Comment: @RayToal sorry for the self-promotion, but you might like [this parsing abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452953/print-macro-values-without-knowing-the-amount-of-macros/47453921#47453921) I put together last year ;)

Comment: Self-promotion appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fully explicit form:

```
Foo bar(Baz f());
```

`bar` is a function that takes a single parameter `f`, which is a function (taking no arguments) returning `Baz`.

Without naming the parameter:

```
Foo bar(Baz ());
```

The reason `bar` ends up taking a pointer to a function is that functions cannot be passed by value, so declaring a parameter as a function automatically decays it into a pointer. The above declaration is equivalent to:

```
Foo bar(Baz (*)());

// or:
Foo bar(Baz (*f)());  // with a named parameter
```

This is similar to `void foo(int [10])` where `int [10]` also means `int *` in a parameter list.

Comment: Should one syntax be used over another (disregarding the use of std::function)? If i were to have a function pointer as a parameter, should I write a normal function declaration and let it decay to a pointer, or should I just write out a function pointer declaration?

Comment: @KrystianS That's a matter of personal taste. I prefer being explicit, so when my parameters are pointers, I declare them as pointers (not as arrays or functions).

Comment: You should define an alias beforehand and use that in the parameter list. For the sake of everyone's sanity.

Answer (score 6):

There are two sets of parentheses in the declaration. The outer set of parentheses are the parameter list of the function `bar`:

```
Foo bar(Baz());
       ^     ^
```

`Baz()` in this declaration is a function type. The parentheses in a function type declaration delimit the parameter list of that function.

```
Foo bar(Baz());
           ^^
```

---

To clarify: In the context of a function parameter declarator, a function type is *adjusted* to be a pointer to a function of that type. So the declaration is in fact equivalent to:

```
Foo bar(Baz(*)());
           ^ ^
```

The highlighted parentheses of this alternative pointer argument declarator are not present in the "pre-adjustement" declaration.

Relevant standard rule:

> [dcl.fct]
>
> The type of a function is determined using the following rules.
> The type of each parameter (including function parameter packs) is determined from its own decl-specifier-seq and declarator.
> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”. ...

Answer (score 3):

> Are the parenthesis present the parenthesis for the parameter list, or are they for the name?

They are for the parameter list.

So:

```
Foo bar(Baz());
```

declares a function which accepts a single parameter of a type *function which returns `Baz` and accepts no parameters.*

This, in turns, equal to a a function declaration which accepts a single parameter of a type *pointer to a function which returns `Baz` and accepts no parameters.* as (from [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)):

> The type of each function parameter in the parameter list is determined according to the following rules:
>
> ...
>
> 3) If the type is a function type F, it is replaced by the type "pointer to F"
>
> ...