# Is there an elegant solution for checking whether a preprocessor symbol is defined or not

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Since preprocessor don't report an error when checking value of preprocessor's symbol that isn't actually defined (usually due to the lack of #include "some_header.h"), I use this cumbersome three line construction with "defined":

```
#if !defined(SOME_SYMBOL)
#error "some symbol isn't defined"
#endif
#if SOME_SYMBOL == 1
// Here is my conditionally compiled code
#endif
```

And the way with "#ifndef" is the same.
Is there a more elegant way to perform this check?

Comment: Nope, that and `#ifndef` is the only way to check if a macro is defined or not.

Comment: Depends. There's [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452953/print-macro-values-without-knowing-the-amount-of-macros) that you may find applicable.

Comment: @StoryTeller so *there*'s where these upvotes came from ;) -- @OP: is `SOME_SYMBOL` always defined to an integer?

Comment: Just in passing, if `SOME_SYMBOL` is not defined `#if SOME_SYMBOL == 1` will evaluate to false. Undefined symbols in this context are treated as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your construction you could use an else block to skip the check for defined:

```
#if SOME_SYMBOL == 1
// Here is my conditionally compiled code
#else
// error
#endif
```

But in principle the comments are right. `#if !defined` and the shorthand `#ifndef` are the two available versions.

Currently, you are checking if `SOME_SYMBOL` is equals to 1. Do you execute different code based on that value ?
If not, you could simply use:

```
#ifdef SOME_SYMBOL
// Here is my conditionally compiled code
#else
// error
#endif
```

And now it's a short step to the typical c++ [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Copying from that wikipedia link, here is a `grandparent.h` file:

```
#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H
#define GRANDPARENT_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDPARENT_H */
```

Now, even if you end up including this header twice, it will only be executed once.

Comment: SOME_SYMBOL can be defined not only as 1. Some other values are valid too.